# Create a space filler template using xslt

Tags: .net, xml, whitespace, xslt-1.0

I need to create two separate templates that fill space. One that occupies 49 spaces and the other fills 549 spaces. I found on template that I thinks may work but I can't really tell what its doing, I'm new to xml.

```
<!-- Template Filler-->
  <xsl:template name="Filler">
    <xsl:param name="fillercount" select="1"/>
    <xsl:if test="$fillercount > 0">
      <table class="tabledetails">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="translate(' ', ' ', '&#160;')"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <xsl:call-template name="Filler">
        <xsl:with-param name="fillercount" select="$fillercount - 1"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Is this what I need , and call it with `select="49"` or  am I reading it wrong.
If this is now what I need how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what output you want. If you call this template with parameter 49 the output will contain 49 tables, each containing one row and one colummn, with the content of the cell being a non-breaking space character. The way of generating a non-breaking space character is very strange: the translate() call take a space character as input and then processes it by replacing all spaces by non-breaking spaces. Presumably it's a cut down version of code that was doing something more sensible at some stage.

The basic structure of the code is a recursive template that takes a parameter, say 49, outputs one "thing" (in this case a singleton table), and then calls itself to do the same again N-1 time. That's the appropriate way to do something N times in XSLT 1.0. (In 2.0, you can use `<xsl:for-each select="1 to $N">`, which is much more intuitive for programmers brought up on imperative languages.)